# React JS Program : State

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Hi I'm doing the ReactJS fundamentals course by Tyler Mcginess, there is a form to be submitted like so,

```
  function Prompt ( props ) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{ props.header }</h3>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={ props.onSubmitUser } >
            <div>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Github Username"
                onChange={ props.onUpdateUser }
                value={ props.username }
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <button type="submit" >
                Continue
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And the function to handle the submit is this,

```
 handleOnSubmitUser: function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // if back button pressed.
    var username = this.state.username;
    this.setState({
      username: ""
    })

    // push state
    if ( this.props.routeParams.playerOne ) {
      this.context.router.push({
        pathname: "/battle",
        query: {
          playerOne: this.props.routeParams.playerOne,
          playerTwo: this.state.username
        }
      })
    } else {
      this.context.router.push("/playerTwo/" + this.state.username)
    }
  },
```

The question i have is that how does resetting the state of the username after caching the username result in the username being passed on to the battle route?, givin the current code, shouldn't the empty string as username be passed since it was just initialised in setState?

Answer (score 0):

When `setState()` is called it modifies `this.state` at the end of the function execution. So this.state will not be changed untill the end. So `this.state.username` is still valid.

Note from [React setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

Addendum: if you want some method to happen *after* the state update, you can use a callback in the `setState`, like so:

```
this.setState(
 { username: "" },
 this.someFunc
)
```

In `someFunc` you can access `this.state`, and it will hold the newly updated values, so username will be "".

Comment: I think you left out the most important part of the documentation: the ability to pass a callback that will be invoked after the state has been changed.